# How do disable JavaScript inside an div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an problem with my JavaScript and I'm not sure how to deal with it.

So I'm using this script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('nav a').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
        }, 700);
        return false;
        });
    });
```

The script is making a smooth scroll on my page which I think is really cool, so I don't want to delete it.

But my problem is, that I also have a simple gallery slider on my page, but the JavaScript will effect that gallery slider. It scrolls to the top when clicking on a link in href. The code for the gallery slider is:

```
            <div id="images">
                <img id="billede1" src="http://i.imgur.com/dL3io.jpg" />
                <img id="billede2" src="http://i.imgur.com/qASVX.jpg" />
                <img id="billede3" src="http://i.imgur.com/fLuHO.jpg" />
                <img id="billede4" src="http://i.imgur.com/5Sd3Q.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div id="slider">
                <a href="#billede1">1</a>
                <a href="#billede2">2</a>
                <a href="#billede3">3</a>
                <a href="#billede4">4</a>
            </div>
```

The thing is, I really like the simple code and I'm trying to be better, so I don't want to use some advanced code which I don't understand.

Is is somehow possible to disable the JavaScript not to be working in my div? Or maybe called it something else than the "href"?

I think my "href" is the problem.

So.. Here it is in fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/62dsqLff/
and you can see the problem.

Really thanks. I appreciate it :-)

Comment: can you post your code in a http://jsfiddle.net and can you add your code to your post instead of posting images with a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, sure. Sorry about that :-)

Comment: give us to ur nav bar  code...

Comment: `$('nav a')` suggests that the smooth scroll should only work with links inside `<nav>` element. So if the slider is outside of nav it shouldn't be affected.

Comment: Hey All :-)
I posted it on fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/62dsqLff/

Pawel - problem is that it also work outside the nav a but it shouldn't :(

Comment: @user3172695 works as expected for me http://jsfiddle.net/62dsqLff/1/ (included jQuery) - nav links have a smooth scroll animation while the gallery only jumps to the top of the screen which is the default behavior for anchor links. If you want to avoid this jump you have to re-implement the elegant CSS `:target` solution for your gallery using JS.

Comment: Hey Pawel. Thank you for your respons. I didn't see this comment. Yes, my smooth scrolling is working, but it's the jump on the gallery I want to avoid. I think it's my bad english which did that you couldn't understand ^^

I'm not sure what you mean with re-implement the elegant CSS :target. Can you show me the code for it? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let me share a fiddle for you [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2bxdqu3g/) on this demo I am given new class called `.nav` for your navbar anchor tags. Then rewrite the script like below.

```
 $('a.nav').click(function () {
     alert( $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top);
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
     }, 700);
     // return false;
 });
```

Comment: I think I implemented the things you want me to do, but it doesn't seem to work :(

http://jsfiddle.net/62dsqLff/3/

Comment: It's working.... Please add jquery on js fiddle like this http://jsfiddle.net/62dsqLff/4/

Comment: Your fiddle is working,, Bt u forgot to include jquery on that check his demo http://jsfiddle.net/62dsqLff/5/.

Comment: I have tried in js fiddle and on my website. I'm quite sure that js fiddle told me I didn't have to include jquery. But anyways I still can't get it to work. Try to scroll manually down to my gallery slider and click on one of the number. You will see my problem afterwards. It scrolls up when I click on one of the numbers. I don't want it to do that.

Comment: So I tried to delete the entire script and the gallery slider still "scrolls up". This is weird. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/62dsqLff/6/

I don't think it is the script anyway. Can I somehow lock "     <a href="#billede1">1</a>" to only scroll up to end of div element.

Not sure if I explained it right. lol

Answer (score 0):

Use an id for that anchor, instead of a vague "nav a" which will trigger on any a inside your `nav` element. 
Also prevent default action if you are using an a as a button. 
The right way to create your "return top" script, is to target a button. Instead of `nav a`, create a button, give it an id, and target that id.